# Is it possible to make a 12v1amp adapter to give an output of 12v3amp power?

Tags: amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, amperage, 12v

I got a 12v power adapter with 1 amp rating. I want to use this adapter to drive a motor which atleast requires 2.5amp to run in load. When i connected the 1 amp adapter, the power is not able to drive the motor with load. When i connected the motor to 3 amp adapter its working well, it can drive now perfectly with load. So instrad of buying a new adapter is that possible to convert 1amp output to 3 amp output. ?

Thanks

Comment: Only at a 1/3 duty cycle max.

Comment: Possible but doesn't worth it. A lot of components should be recalculated and placed. The cost of these components and effort will be higher than a new 12V/3A supply, believe me.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

Well, as a thought experiment, you could upgrade your existing 12V adapter, but that would amount to replacing every component in it, including the case since the larger transformer won't fit.

This would be wasted effort, since you can purchase the adapter you need for a very affordable price.

Answer (score -1):

This violates the law of conservation of energy. Power output (12V*3A=36W) more power input(12V*1A=12W). Therefore, it is impossible.